# What is the utility of validate-parameter attribute?

Tags: moqui

Thank you for answering my previous questions and I appreciate the effort put in by you in developing Moqui.
In the field tag there is an attribute of validate-parameter so could please elaborate the use of it and how to use that attribute. Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be specific, it sounds like you are looking at the XML Form field element (form-list.field, form-single.field).

A form field can be validated based on the validation settings in a service parameter (there are many validation options there) or an entity field (just a couple validation options there). This is done automatically when a form submits to a transition that has a single service-call element (i.e. not an actions element), and these attributes are populated automatically. You can also specify manually which service/parameter or entity/field to use for validation.

This is all part of the support in the framework to do client side validation with JavaScript using server-side validation settings. Note that the validations are also done on the server, but you don't have to define/implement them twice.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it by giving a sample code for example